# ssis control flow loop

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

[image]

I need an SSIS package that loops back to the initial execute task after the wait for delay block is executed. here is the logic for the below package: execute SQL task executes a set of commands and after that if a condition is met, the second process(preparation sql task 1 and so on) will be executed. if the condition is not met, it will wait for some time and re-run the first task(execute sql task). I am stuck here and cannot go any further. please help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a For Loop Container. For an example, see the mssqltips article [Configure the SQL Server Integration Services For Loop Container](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3686/configure-the-sql-server-integration-services-for-loop-container/).

Comment: How can I loop Execute SQL Task and connect it to other task out side loop with precedence constraint?

Comment: You can connect your loop container to another task via a precedence constraint in the usual way. Just drag the connector from the loop container.